# Need help figuring out how to build a Questionaire based on objects in Salesforce, display in an Experience Cloud Page with generated URL

Tags: sobject, experience-cloud

I'm trying to wrap my head around something pretty complicated.

Users want to dynamically build out a form with Questions and Answers that will display on a Experience Cloud Page.

There will be a bank of Questions and Answers that are stored in a customs object call Question and Answer bank. Looks like this

Question__c (Text)

Answer1__c (Text)

Answer2__c (Text)

Answer3__c (Text)

Answer4__c (Text)

Users will pick and choose the Questions and Answers they want to use in the form via a wizard I will build.

Once they have their selection, I am to create a form on an Experience Cloud Page with a generated URL, the form has these same object based Questions with the Answers.

This is the part that I am quite stuck on. How would I create the form? How do I convert these object based Questions and Answers into checkboxes? How would I know if the question is suppose to be open ended?

Comment: This is a pretty complex app you're talking about. There are multiple AppExchange products that serve this need. It is not answerable in the scope of a Stack Exchange answer.

Comment: @DavidReed I'm afraid the use case is to specific. I think will need some way for them to confirm if the question is a multiple choice or open-ended. But how I display this in the community is tricky.